# Is there a way to verify a signed XML in Java

Tags: java, digital-signature, .net

[.NET has this great way to sign and then verify the signature of an XML file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229950(v=vs.110).aspx). Is there a way in Java to verify an XML file that .NET has signed this way?

Comment: A simple Google search gives this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/XMLDigitalSignature.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but I believe to suppliment what user2316037 stated I believe javax.xml.crypto.dsig which allows you to sign and validate an XML digital signature.I believe that is what you are looking to use.

Retrieved from:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/dig-signature-api-140772.html